# jQuery Datepicker doesn't response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i'm using this very simple datepicker code from the jQuery UI docs but it doesn't work on my Mac:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="date-picker" />
    <script>
        $("#date-picker").datepicker();
    </script>
</body>
```

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to include jquery before, also you have two references to jquery js, check: http://jsfiddle.net/bwjb02rf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI is dependent upon jQuery.

Therefore you need to include the jQuery script before the jQuery UI script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

No need to include jQuery twice either. The above will suffice.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dd3j255p/).

Comment: But isn't the first line related to jQuery UI?

Comment: The first line is the stylesheet. In this case, its order doesn't effect the scripts (`.js` files) below it.

Comment: First line is css of jQuery UI.You can load it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should add jquery before adding jqueryui.
You added jquery twice.Remove one

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>-->


    <body>
    <input type="text" id="date-picker" />
    <script>
        $("#date-picker").datepicker();
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

yeahh include jquery before jquery ui

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="date-picker" />
    <script>
        $("#date-picker").datepicker();
    </script>
</body>
```